# How to debug neural nets and GA

Tags: debugging, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I made a genetic algorithm which seemed to be working fine until I hooked it to a neural net, both together aren't working, the neural net is probably the problem but and I'm not 100% sure the GA is fine too.

I don't really know where should I start to debugging them. I'm almost considering deleting the whole thing and start over(I'm working almost a month in this). But before I do that I come here to ask for general tips to debug those two.

Is there a way to test if the GA is working as expected? Perhaps a already proven problem to a known solution to compare it and try to optimize to that solution?

And how about the neural net, how can I find if it is working as expected?

The two programs are conceptually and scripting-wise fine as far as I can see. But somehow if I put them together they just don't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Testing the GA

> Let the GA find a string of 1's from a the sequence of numbers from 1-9.

### The procedure

1. Let the genes be a combination of the integers 123456789.
2. Create a gene pool (initial population) with a random permutation of the integers of size 9.
3. Let the fitness function rate how close each gene is to the correct permutation: `111111111`

As a hint: the genetic algorithm should find this sequence within 30-40 generations. How fast the algorithm is to converge on the correct sequence depends on your fitness function (heuristic function).

Comment: A trivial heuristic function would be: `int(gene.value) - 111111111`